# Editing files on Raspberry PI over ssh and with root privileges

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, ubuntu

Setup: local machine has PopOS 20 (based on Ubuntu 20), remote server is running Raspbian Stretch.

I have been editing files on the remote server from the terminal, over `ssh` and with `nano`, but I'm starting to find this set up quite laborious. I have found different solutions on-line:

- I connected the remote server to the local machine's file manager, which proved straightforward and convenient but does not allow me to edit files that require sudo privileges
- I found the [`RemoteSubl` plugin](https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl) for Sublime Text, a text editor that I know well and find very comfortable, but I cannot find a way to edit files with root privileges.

Is there a way to gain root privileges on either of those solutions? Or are there any alternative you would suggest as optimal in terms of security and usability?

Comment: I find sudo reminds me these files are vital and do not fiddle with them that much.  You could always set up Samba/NETATALK to use the root user BUT files created in home folders will be owned by root and that gives normal users issues then running them.  It really is not good just to use root - basics of security teaches give users the minimum to do their job and no more.  (Says the guy who has just been notified his old email along with 68 million others has been leaked again).

Comment: Emacs and TRAMP.

Comment: Thanks @Swedgin, I am not familiar with Emacs but it seems to do exactly what I need. I wonder if I could do something similar with other text editors.

Comment: No sorry. Another way would be to edit your sudoers file (on the server) and set the useraccount to not have to enter password, or just for `nano`. E.g something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt